# Function Subroutine : Boolean

Tags: vba, excel, function, if-statement, boolean

I am using an if statement in my procedure that calls upon my Boolean function; however, when I run the program, it always outputs the message as if the function were true.

```
Public Function INR() As Boolean
    If Avg < 1.5 & SD < 0.5 Then
        INR = True
    Else
        INR = False
    End If
End Function

Public Sub PatientINR()
    Range("B2", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Name = "Name"
    Dim cell As Range, reply As String, i As Long, x As Variant, Avg As Long, SD As Long
    reply = InputBox("Enter patient's name", "INR", "Madelyn Carberry")
        i = 1
    x = Range("Name").Cells(i)
    Do Until x = reply
        i = i + 1
        x = Range("Name").Cells(i)
    Loop
    Avg = Range("Name").Cells(i, 17)
    SD = Range("Name").Cells(i, 18)
    Call INR
    If INR = True Then
        MsgBox reply & "'s INR record is satisfactory for the procedure"
    End If
    If INR = False Then
        MsgBox reply & "'s INR record is not satisfactory for the procedure"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How is `Avg` and `SD` set in the function. A user function is supposed to deal with local variables and arguments only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the data to the function.  Change the first line of the function to:

```
Public Function INR(Avg As Double, SD As Double) As Boolean
```

Then when you call the function pass the variables:

```
If INR(Avg,SD) Then
```

As is, the values are not being passed and as such are 0 when it tests.  Which will return true.

As you see above you do not need the `= True` it is a boolean and therefore Already True or False.

Also do not test for False just use Else:

```
If INR(Avg,SD) Then
    MsgBox reply & "'s INR record is satisfactory for the procedure"
Else
    MsgBox reply & "'s INR record is not satisfactory for the procedure"
End If
```

Also `&` is used in Concatenation use the word `And`:

```
If Avg < 1.5 And SD < 0.5 Then
```

The function gets called in the if, there is no need for `Call INR`, just use it as any other function.

Also it is good practice to name the sheet on which this is run.  We can do that with a `With` Block:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
    'Do your code
End With
```

Instead of creating a named range lets use a Range variable:

```
Set rng = .Range("B:B")
```

Lets speed things up a little and remove the loop.  We can use Match to find the row with:

```
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(reply, rng, 0)
```

If the name is found it will return the row in which it was found.  If not it will return an error.  I have opted to skip if in error and thus `i` will remain 0 and we can test for that before continuing.

INR's default will be False so we do not need to set it and save some typing:

```
INR = (Avg < 1.5 And SD < 0.5)
```

Should be sufficient

So:

```
Public Function INR(Avg As Double, SD As Double) As Boolean
    INR = (Avg < 1.5 And SD < 0.5)
End Function

Public Sub PatientINR()

    Dim cell As Range, reply As String, i As Long
    Dim Avg As Double, SD As Double
    Dim rng As Range
    reply = InputBox("Enter patient's name", "INR", "Madelyn Carberry")
    i = 0
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
        Set rng = .Range("B:B")
        On Error Resume Next
            i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(reply, rng, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If i <> 0 Then
            Avg = .Cells(i, 17)
            SD = .Cells(i, 18)
            If INR(Avg, SD) Then
                MsgBox reply & "'s INR record is satisfactory for the procedure"
            Else
                MsgBox reply & "'s INR record is not satisfactory for the procedure"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Name not Found"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```